# Amazon In-App Purchasing Subscription receipt has null subscriptionPeriod

Tags: web-applications, in-app-purchase, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement Amazon's IAP in a web app, but the receipt returned from the purchase has a null subscriptionPeriod object, so I can't check the endDate to verify the subscription. Amazon's sample app is also not working for the subscription item (the blue button) for this same reason. I have tried running it through the RVSSandbox verification server and get:
   `{"message":"Failed to parse iap token","status":false}`
[HERE](http://www.tk-squared.com/Timothy/IAPSample/) is Amazon's sample app hosted on a web server, the only change being that I did a console.log(receipt) so you can see the null subscriptionPeriod. Any help here would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Amazon said [HERE](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/68649/subscriptionperiod-is-always-null-in-receipt.html) that this behavior is "as expected" although it is not at all what is given in the developer reference, and indeed their own sample code is un-workable because of it. They basically have said "do as much as you can and then upload for beta testing for a real test." Not ideal imho, but they have the customers, so what can you do?